# Circular seating arrangement with gap

Tags: combinatorics

> The number of ways in which 4 men and 3 ladies sit at a round table so
> that no two ladies sit together is
>
> (a) 144
>
> (b) 72
>
> (c) 120
>
> (d) None of these

In this question are men and women indistinguishable? I mean one man can not be different from another because we are classifying them on the criteria of gender.

Another question, how would I incorporate the gap idea into the circular arrangement thing?

I have already found this problem can be modelled using a septagon

Comment: If indistinguishable then usually not "men and women" are used, but e.g. "blue balls and pink balls".

Comment: uh, that is like just memorizing the question. I am asking how to infer that from the English they have written

Comment: It is just a comment. Not an answer.

Comment: Humans are not identical. Unless it's told to ignore that.

Comment: I'm arguing that if you group a things based on one property like sex/color then they would be. If you were grouping on personality or something sure , there would be permutations and all

Answer (score 1):

I think all seven people are distinguishable, because in general people are distinguishable. Gender is used for the "not next to one another" restriction, rather than creating distinction.

Also, consider what would happen if men were indistinguishable and women were indistinguishable. There would be exactly one legal seating (or seven, depending on whether you care where around the table the two men who sit next to one another sit (which now that I think about it is another thing we don't know whether it's supposed to matter: do we care who sits closest to the door?)) That's probably not what is asked for here, even without looking at the multiple choices.

But ultimately, this is a game of mind reading, and you **have** to guess. There is no way to know for absolute certain without asking the problem author.

Answer (score 0):

In most of the cases people are distinguishable unless mentioned otherwise.

Considering all the people to be distinguishable, we can incorporate the gap method by firstly seating all the men around the circle in $\frac{4!}{4}=3!$ ways. between these 4 men there are 4 gaps created around the circle. we then select 3 of these gaps and permute the women in those to get the total no. of ways.

Ans. = $(3!).\binom{4}{3}.(3!)$ = 144